# span minipage content over multiple pages

Tags: tables, luatex, minipage

I'm writing my own layout for the CV (that I'd like to convert into a public class), and I'm trying to have a two-column layout like the following:

[image]

where for each section the summary on the left side is a minipage, and the content another one, but wider.

As soon as I added more work experiences, I realized that LaTeX tried to put on a new minipage. I have made some search and the community suggests I should use [flowfram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271410/how-to-make-minipage-spanning-multiple-pages/299656#299656), but I tried to take inspiration from other classes, where I saw some workaround using `tabular`.

The pros of flowfram is its easiness, but I would like to put each section's title with the content (well, as you can see not exactly. I place a little space above). Tabular seems to be the answer, but it sounds like the web in the old 90's.

So here is the question: which of the two I should use? Are there any other ways to accomplish that neatly?

Comment: »Which of the two I should use?«  Closing as opinion-based.  A proper questions must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 4):

A breakable sort of `minipage` can be done with the `tcolorbox` package.

The following could do the job. Observe that the `WORK EXPERIENCE` box is broken from page 1 to page 2.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{cvbox}[2][]{%
  blanker,
  leftupper=4cm,
  after skip=8mm,%   enlarge distance to the next box
  title=#2,
  breakable,
  fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
  coltitle=cyan,
  fontupper=\sffamily,%
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{cvbox}{SUMMARY}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{cvbox}

\begin{cvbox}{HIGHTLIGHTS}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Methodical
    \item Blabla
  \end{itemize}
\end{cvbox}

\begin{cvbox}{WORK EXPERIENCE}
  \lipsum[2-5]
\end{cvbox}

\begin{cvbox}{CONCLUSION}
  \lipsum[6]
\end{cvbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]