# Spreading text over two minipage/tcolorbox environments, over two different pages

Tags: tcolorbox, minipage

I would like to define two `minipage` (or `tcolorbox`, I don't have much constraint there) environments, on two different pages, that I would like to fill with some text, and I would like LaTeX to spread the text between these two `minipage` environments automatically.

In other words, I would like to declare two `minipage` environments, separated by a `\newpage` command, and to declare the text that will fill the first `minipage` environment first, and then, once that first `minipage` environment is full, to send the remainder to the second `minipage` environment. It would be something like that (this is not a reduced example, because I have no idea where to start):

```
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t][16cm][t]{18cm}
First part of my text.
\end{minipage}

~\newpage

\begin{minipage}[t][15cm][t]{18cm}
Second part of my text.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Of course, I can manually break my text into two parts, and write the first part in the first `minipage` environment and the second part of the text in the second `minipage` environment. However, I actually would like LaTeX to do that automatically (I am writing a template for a monthly report, and the text that has to fit in these two environments is loaded from a single .txt file, of variable size - so everytime a change in that file is implemeted, I would have to look for the proper position where I should break it).

I also need the `~\newpage` command to control for the page break because I have to place stuff using `texblock*` environments on both the first and the second page - so if I let LaTeX make the second page by itself, all my `texblock*` commands will be put on the first page only.

It would look like that:

```
Page 1:
 _______________________________________
|    Stuff positioned with textblock    |
|_______________________________________|

     _______________________________
    |                               |
    |                               |
    |     First part of my text     |
    |                               |
    |                               |
    |_______________________________|

 _______________________________________
| Other Stuff positioned with textblock |
|_______________________________________|

Page 2:
 _______________________________________
| Other Stuff positioned with textblock |
|_______________________________________|

     _______________________________
    |                               |
    |                               |
    |    Second part of my text     |
    |                               |
    |                               |
    |_______________________________|

 _______________________________________
| Other Stuff positioned with textblock |
|_______________________________________|
```

Would you have any idea on how to do that?

Comment: The `framed` or `shaded` environments automatically break over pages if  they do not fit on a single page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found (after a lot of time) this link [How to make minipage spanning multiple pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271410/how-to-make-minipage-spanning-multiple-pages?rq=1)
I discover the flowfram package, it should meet your needs.

If it's the same textblock on each page, no need for an option in \newstaticframe[1]{\textwidth}{.25\texttheight}{0pt}{.75\texttheight}[p1]%head

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{flowfram,lipsum}

    \newstaticframe{\textwidth}{.25\textheight}{0pt}{.75\textheight}[p]
    \newstaticframe[1]{\textwidth}{.25\textheight}{0pt}{.75\textheight}[p1]%head
    %\newstaticframe[1]{\textwidth}{.7\textheight}{0pt}{-15cm}[bp1]% bottom
    % if the same text on every page the option is not necessary
    \newstaticframe{\textwidth}{.7\textheight}{0pt}{-15cm}[bp]% bottom
    %% for the other pages (if not the same text)
    \newstaticframe[2]{\textwidth}{.25\textheight}{0pt}{.75\textheight}[p2]%head
    \newstaticframe[3]{\textwidth}{.25\textheight}{0pt}{.75\textheight}[p3]%head
    \newstaticframe[4]{\textwidth}{.25\textheight}{0pt}{.75\textheight}[p4]%head
    \setallstaticframes{valign=t}

    \newflowframe{0.7\textwidth}{0.5\textheight}{.2\textwidth}{5cm}
    %
    \pagestyle{empty}

    \begin{document}


    \begin{staticcontents*}{p1}
        \large{TEXT of the first page}
    \end{staticcontents*}

    \begin{staticcontents*}{p2}
        \large{TEXT of the second page}
    \end{staticcontents*}

    \begin{staticcontents*}{p3}
        \large{TEXT of the third page}
    \end{staticcontents*}

    \begin{staticcontents*}{p4}
        \large{TEXT of the fourth page}
    \end{staticcontents*}

    \begin{staticcontents*}{bp}
        \large{TEXT of the bottom of all pages}% it can change
    \end{staticcontents*}

    \lipsum[1-4]
    \framebreak
    \lipsum[5-10]
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you already know the available space on your page, you can use `magazine` library from `tcolorbox` and place every fragment on different pages, even in wrong order.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable, 
    reset box array, store to box array, 
    empty,
    break at=10cm,
    height fixed for = all,
    valign=center]
    \lipsum[1-3]
\end{tcolorbox}

\consumetcboxarray{1}{colback=blue!30}

\newpage

\consumetcboxarray{2}{colback=red!30}

\end{document}
```

[image]